# What are the risks of having the method implementation of an interface in a parent class when the parent class does not implement the interface?

Tags: java, oop, interface, implementation

Let's say I have this interface and these classes:

```
public interface ITest 
{
   void test();
}

public class Parent
{
   public void test()
   {
       System.out.println("test");
   }
}

public class Child extends Parent implements ITest
{

}
```

Now I know the project will compile but are there any risk that this pattern generates an error at runtime?

I'm asking because I need to use a method that already exists in the parent of the class that implements the interface. Editing the project in which the Parent and Child classes are located should be a last resort solution as it would not be backward compatible. (version wise)

It does seem to work too but it goes against my understanding of OOP. It would actually make my life a lot easier if I can use this pattern without a risk.

Comment: I guess the risk is that someone changes `Parent` without understanding the requirement, and `Child` breaks.

Comment: The risk isn't really any different than any other risk in programming.  If someone makes a breaking change, the build breaks and needs to be fixed.  This inheritance structure may be an uncommon case, but there's nothing inherently wrong with it.

Comment: Why would editing `Parent` to implement `ITest` not be backward compatible?

Comment: @jaco0646 because the project in which Parent is is versionned and the App that uses the said project must support all versions of that project. So an instance of the App entity that uses the older version to desierialize (before the code change) wouldn't use the new implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't mix class files from different compile runs (at which point, *everything* is out the window; you obviously cannot protect against someone changing both Parent and ITest, recompiling just those two, and leaving your earlier compilation result of compiling Child (`Child.class`) untouched), there is no risk here.

Comment: Since the Parent class is in a project of it's own and is versionned there is not risk. The project where the Child class is references the Parent project (Maven) with it's version. Both project are build/compiled/deployed by a pipeline so if compilation fails i'll be informed right away. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is perfectly acceptable and there is nothing wrong with it.

When a class `implements` an interface, Java compiler simply checks for presence/compatibility of methods declared in the interface; it does not matter how and from where the implementation is coming from.

However, this practice might be confusing for a reader, so I recommend writing a good comment that explains why it is done in such a way.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to pass instances of `Child` as type `ITest`, then the risk is that you might violate the Liskov Substitution Principle. As mentioned, there is no problem syntactically; but do the semantics of the the `test()` method implementation in `Parent` conform to those of the `test()` method declaration in `ITest`?

For example, if the meaning of the test declaration is something like, execute a test of foo and throw a runtime exception if it fails; but the meaning of the implementation is, execute a test of bar and print a message if it fails, then a consumer of `Child` as an instance of `ITest` is likely to be broken (even though it compiles).

Comment: Yeah it does it's actually just a getter on a property contained in the Parent class.